# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException caught when running the Vertx 4 sample Junit 5 test

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle

When running the sample test generated by start.vertx.io and got the following info.

- Vertx 4.0
- Java 11 and Java 15
- Windows 10

```sh
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: 
The test execution timed out. Make sure your asynchronous code includes calls to 
either VertxTestContext#completeNow(), VertxTestContext#failNow() or Checkpoint#flag()
```

I added a GitHub action for it.

https://github.com/hantsy/vertx-sandbox/runs/1535205549

The `@BeforeEach` itself failed.

```java
@ExtendWith(VertxExtension.class)
public class TestMainVerticle {

    @BeforeEach
    void deploy_verticle(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) {
        vertx.deployVerticle(new MainVerticle(), testContext.succeeding(id -> testContext.completeNow()));
    }

    @Test
    void verticle_deployed(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) throws Throwable {
        testContext.completeNow();
    }
}
```

I am new to the Vertx platform, really not sure the reason from Vertx's internal side. From the exception info, I can not find the cause root in my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a `startPromise.complete()` to my `start(Promise<Void> startPromise)` to resolve this issue.